# Windows Run Box as Admin

Tags: windows, permissions, runas

I am desperately looking for a way to get the Run box as Admin by default.
I am using Windows 8.1 and remember I had this feature as Admin with Windows 7.
[image]

I can surely use workaround such as runas, CommandPrompt or PowerShell as Admin but this isn't what I am looking for.
(note: I am local admin)

[image]

So this is what I would like to get when I hold Windows+R  :
[image]

Can anyone help me with this ? I couldn't find any answer on Microsoft or Google. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to get to the Run dialog box using only Windows + R? Because if not and you only need the Run dialog with admin privileges, there's a workaround by running taskmgr as admin then File > New Task Run.

Comment: I believe this appears when the user account control setting is set to never notify.  I don't have a windows 8 box in front of me so I cant say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as UAC is enabled and you aren't logged in as the literal 'administrator' account, you can't without some manual steps.  The Run dialog box is spawned as a child process of your non-elevated explorer.exe shell which makes anything it launches also non-elevated.

In order to run elevated processes from the Run dialog, your explorer.exe shell needs to be elevated.  There are a number of ways to do this. But the only permanent way I know of is to disable UAC which is generally a bad idea.

Instead, I usually do this on demand when necessary.

- Start by launching an elevated cmd.exe or taskmgr.exe.
- Now close any Explorer windows and kill your existing explorer.exe process (make sure it's actually your process if there are others logged in).
- From your elevated process, launch a new explorer.exe which will reload your standard Windows shell environment
- Now you have effectively disabled UAC for the duration of your login session and anything you run from the Run dialog will be elevated
- To turn it back off, just logout (not just disconnect if using RDP)

Answer (score 0):

Explorer is spawn as non-admin when UAC is disabled on a local admin account.

Here a batch script to spawn explorer as admin even with UAC being disabled.

The script can be saved as "**elevexplorer.bat**" in **%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** to be triggered when the user logs in.

I do not necessarily recommend using it as I believe that Microsoft designed it this way for a good reason (security-wise). For testing only.

```
@echo off
:: This script kill explorer and relaunch it in elevelated mode. (UAC disabled)
:: It requires to be a local administrator of the machine
::#############################################
::# AUTHOR: FlORIAN BIDABE @ENELASS           #
::# BIDABE.ZAPTO.COM                          #
::# VERSION 0.1  RELEASE DATE July 29 2015    #
::# Spawn Internet Explorer as admin          #
::#############################################

:: Create sudo (Credits goes to Andre.Ziegler / TechNet)
echo @echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") ^> ^%%temp^%%\sudo.tmp.vbs > %temp%\sudo.cmd
echo @echo args = Right("%%*", (Len("%%*") - Len("%%1"))) ^>^> ^%%temp^%%\sudo.tmp.vbs >> %temp%\sudo.cmd
echo @echo objShell.ShellExecute "%%1", args, "", "runas" ^>^> ^%%temp^%%\sudo.tmp.vbs >> %temp%\sudo.cmd
echo @cscript ^%%temp^%%\sudo.tmp.vbs >> %temp%\sudo.cmd

echo Restart Explorer as administrator...
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
%temp%\sudo explorer
ping 0.0.0.0 -n > nul
```